# Xcode 9 Authentication fails pushing to Git Server

Tags: xcode, git

I have a set up a private remote git server (not GitHub).

I can perform all operations fine from the command line without problem. This server also works fine with IntelliJ.

From within Xcode I can PULL changes.  But mysteriously I cannot push changes even though both require authentication.  I am using SSH.

I've seen lots of posts about windows authentication, IIS, and other special cases.  But I have not seen anything about being able to pull but not push.  And I have no idea where Xcode might write any logging.  At the user level it just says Authentication failed.  I am using SSH (no certs).

Any advice on where to even start looking would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I can perform all operations fine from the command line without problem" Then do that. Problem solved.

Comment: Git allows configuring different URLs for fetches (that's the main part of "pull") and pushes—all communicating with *the same* repo. So I'd start verifying this. First try looking at the output of `git remote -v`. Then try to figure out how to enable in Xcode some debug output of the operation it carries out, and try looking at how it calls Git in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Posting for posterity, but: check your ssh keys if you are using key-based auth.  I was having a devil of a time trying to get Xcode to do any git ops, until I changed the ssh setup to use an RSA key.  ECDSA doesn't work.  Not sure about any other keys, but apple docs on setting up continuous integration with xcode always talk about RSA keys, which was my clue.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems this has been broken since Xcode 7, two years ago.

THE solution (all caps because this is the ONLY thing that works) is to put the password in the git server URL.  So you can have function or security - but not both.  Apparently the Xcode parsing of the git config is VERY VERY defective.

```
git config --edit
```

Use THIS exact syntax for the git server URL (assuming ssh without certificate)

```
url = ssh://username:passwd@server/path/to/project.git
```

Ugly but works.